# Is there a better term for "non-negative"?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, education, ordered-groups

Real numbers $x$ satisfying $x \geq 0$ are said to be *non-negative*. Some alternative phrases include *positive or zero* and *at least zero.* However, I find these phrases to be unsatisfactory, for a couple of reasons.

**One.** With the exception of non-negative, these phrases are a bit long-winded, and they don't function like adjectives, which is also annoying. For example, the sentence "the natural numbers are the positive or zero integers," doesn't sound particularly grammatical.

**Two.** The logical negation in the phrase "non-negative" is slightly confusing. I think it probably confuses new students, since I've been studying mathematics for a long time and still sometimes feel a moment of confusion when I hear this phrase.

**Three.** It's a fundamental concept that's introduced early on in people's mathematical careers and relates to lots of basic stuff people need to master. It's involved in the very important law $$a \geq 0 \rightarrow (x \leq y \rightarrow ax \leq ay),$$ its the domain on which $\sqrt{x^2} = x$, and its the codomain of every norm and metric. It also describes the length/area/volume of compact shapes, which are pretty much the only shapes people look at in high school. Hence having a short and spiffy term for it would be pedagogically useful.

**Four.** Mathematically speaking, it doesn't generalize well. In a partially-ordered field or partially-ordered ring, non-negative ought to mean $\neg(x < 0)$, which is a weaker condition than $x \geq 0$.

> **Question.**
>
> When I was younger, I came up with the word "positic" to describe numbers $x$ satisfying $x \geq 0$. My friends toyed with it for awhile, but we ultimately found it was a bit cringeworthy phonetically, and eventually we stopped using it. I'd be interested to know if there's anywhere in the world where there's a word for this concept, or if any words have been proposed. In short: is there a better term for "non-negative"?

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you have the tonic accent fall on "positic"? On the "o" (pòsitic) or on the first "i" (posìtic)?

Comment: My gut says that if there were a better alternative, we'd be using it. Maybe not all of us all the time, as habits are hard to break, but it would be in active use. That being said, _strictly_ speaking, $x\geq0$ ought to be positive and $x>0$ ought to be strictly positive or properly positive. To align more with how basically every other order-related word is used.

Comment: Consider the reals as $1\times1$ matrices and call them *positive semidefinite*? Then maybe shorten it to *semipositive*?

Comment: Call them *rootable*, since they have real square roots (and cube roots, and fourth roots, and so on). Just be careful when in Australia.

Comment: @Arthur That's the convention in French.

Comment: The really confusing thing is the double negation, as in the sentence "let $S$ be a set containing no non-negative integers". Confusing at least to French people !

Comment: @Gae.S., in the way we were saying it, the tonos was on the "o".

Comment: @Rahul, great suggestion!

Comment: @J.-E.Pin, well, I'm Greek, and I find it super confusing :)

Comment: @OscarCunningham, what's the relevant French word?

Comment: @goblin "Positif" https://mathoverflow.net/a/247594/4613

Comment: I don't find anything wrong with the term "non-negative" in this context. It may mean different things in other contexts...but those are other contexts.

Comment: I have heard one or two people give math talks in English where the lecturer said at the beginning something like "I will use the french 'positif' for 'nonnegative', and distinguish it from 'positive'." It worked okay, but is far from common and would be a challenge for nonnative (there's "non" again) speakers who have difficulty distinguishing unvoiced f and voiced v.

Comment: "Positive-ish". ;)

Comment: Personally I vote for "quasitive."

Comment: For the record - I use "unsigned integer" to mean "non-negative integer" as this term already exists in software. I am strongly involved in both software and mathematics. Mathematically, the term "signed integer" would just be the same as "integer".  Trying to force a completely new term in a course only works if you are famous.